# How to get a click event for each li, not all

Tags: jquery, onclick

im trying to get this button to show a hidden div `onClick`within each li that will show over the post div in an absolute positioning. The problem is, on click, it's showing all of the hidden div's for all li's. Im using wordpress + buddypress, so each li's id has a unique ID

```
<li id="activity-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>" class="activity" >

  <div id="post"></div>

  <div class="action">
   //my pop in stuff
  </div>

  <div id="post-actions-bar">   
    <button id="show">show</button>
  </div>

</li>
```

and here's my jquery that I thought would work.
NOTE: I'm using `.on()` because there will be li's added dynamically.

```
$(document).on(  'click' , '.activity button#show' , function() {
   $('.action').show();
});
```

In a sense it does work, but it shows all of the `.action div's` for every li on the screen, I only want to show the one for that li's button that was clicked. I tried using `.each()` but It's not working. I'm ding something wrong (obviously lol)

Any ideas?

Comment: On a side note, if `li` is recursive, you shouldn't be using `show` as the button's `id` since that will result in multiple elements having the same `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the event handler `$(this)` refers to the one button that was clicked. So what you need to do is start from `$(this)` and [traverse the DOM tree](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to get to the one `.action` that you want to show.

This is one way to do it, which I find preferable:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.activity button' , function() {
   $(this).closest(".activity").find(".action").show();
});
```

As an aside, your HTML implies that you are using the same `id` value for multiple elements. That's illegal and should be fixed -- it's only a matter of time before it causes trouble. Most of the time it's fine to assign a shared `class` to your elements instead of the same `id` and work with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this).closest('.activity').find('.action')` instead of `$('.action')`.

The reason for this is pretty simple - when you use `$('.action')` you simply retrieve all elements matching the selector `.action` which is completely unrelated to the event.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the ul instead of the document to catch the click event

```
$('ul#parentofyouractivitylis').on('click', '.activity button', function(){
    $(this).closest(".activity").find(".action").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do them with a single bind since `.action` can't be reached from `.activity` or `button#show` using the same method. You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.activity', function() {
    $(this).find(".action").show();
});

$(document).on('click', '#show', function() {
    $(this).closest(".action").show();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5ABt/) is a fiddle for you:

```
// html
<li>
    <div>Loading 1...</div>
</li>
<li>    
    <div>Loading 2...</div>
</li>​

// css
div
{
    display:none;
}​

// js
$("li").click(function(){

   // hide any showing ones
   $("li > div").hide(); 

   $(this).find("> div").show();

});
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Updated, just woke up, sorry!