# jquery loop through elements by incrementing ID

Tags: jquery

I have about a dozen events to check and all selectors are similarly (iteratively) named. How could I shorten this routine?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#del_od1', function() {
        $('#change_od1').val('YES');
        $('#span_od1').html('(Deleted)');
        $('#status_od1').val('DELETED');
    });
    $(document).on('click','#del_od2', function() {
        $('#change_od2').val('YES');
        $('#span_od2').html('(Deleted)');
        $('#status_od2').val('DELETED');
    });
    $(document).on('click','#del_od3', function() {
        $('#change_od3').val('YES');
        $('#span_od3').html('(Deleted)');
        $('#status_od3').val('DELETED');
    });
});
```

This question is poorly named. Could someone also suggest a more precise title and I'll change it to that before accepting the answer.

---

EDIT:

An entire table structure is echoed out in response to an ajax call.  The top of the table is like this:

```
$r = '
    <table id="DocTable">
        <tr>
            <th width="170">Document Title</th>
            <th width="170">MetShare FN</th>
            <th width="50">Action</th>
            <th width="50">Delete</th>
        </tr>';
```

Followed by a couple of irrelevant rows containing information as requested in the call. Then this is appended to the previous bit, and the whole thing echoed out as `echo $r;`.

```
$rest_docs =  $aProj['all_project_docs'];
$ocnt = 0;
if ($rest_docs !== ''){
    $ocnt = $ocnt + 1;
    $aRest_docs = explode('?',$rest_docs);
    foreach($aRest_docs as $doc){
        $aDoc_parts = explode('|',$doc);

        $r = $r . '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$aDoc_parts[0].'</td>
            <td>
                <span id="span_od' . $ocnt . '">
                    <a href="'.$aDoc_parts[1].'" target="blank">
                    '. $aDoc_parts[1] .'
                    </a>
                </span>
                <input type="hidden" id="status_od' . $ocnt . '" name="status_od' . $ocnt . '">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="change_od' . $ocnt . '" class="normal" href="#">change</a>
                <input type="file" id="if_od' . $ocnt . '" name="if_od' . $ocnt . '" style="display:none">
                <input type="text" style="display:none">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="del_od' . $ocnt . '">delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}

echo $r;
```

Comment: A bit of HTML would be nice! Are the elements are nested?

Comment: I added more of the code. It is HTML echoed out by PHP, but it appears in the DOM as the above HTML.

Comment: You'd do better to avoid an id based solution here. A single class on all the elements should be sufficient. I'd show you how, but mobile devices are not for coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *[jsBin (just for example) demo](http://jsbin.com/iturun/2/edit)*

a common thing to all this names...

```
   del_od1
change_od1
  span_od1
status_od1

is:      1      :)   (a number, and so for all other elements)
```

...so we need to grab it! look:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','[id^=del_od]', function() {//^="starts with selector"

        var num = this.id.split('od')[1];  // returns our number from the id!
        // from now on we can use our var "num" :

        $('#change_od'+ num).val ('YES');
        $('#span_od'  + num).html('(Deleted)');
        $('#status_od'+ num).val ('DELETED');
    });
});
```

Comment: Not only did your code work for me, but you also provided an example. Dude, you're a teacher at heart. Thanks.

Comment: :) You're welcome @gibberish ! Really glad you like it and that was helpful! Happy coding

Comment: First time ive seen and ussed [id^]... Great stuff!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        $(document).on('click','#del_od' + i, (function(index) {
            return function() {
                $('#change_od' + index).val('YES');
                $('#span_od' + index).html('(Deleted)');
                $('#status_od' + index).val('DELETED');
            };
        })(i));
    }
});
```

However, it is extremely likely that you could achieve the same effect without this brutish coding style by utilizing classes instead of ids and leveraging the information you have about the structure of the document. Can you give an example of that?

Comment: Not positive, but I think you have a variable scope problem. I have a feeling this will always update the `9` version of the elements.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: I should really go to bed. Fixed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @gibberish: You can (and really should) use classes. When each element is clicked, navigate back up to the parent `<tr>` and then down to the elements you want to find. You can see how e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316712/how-to-get-a-click-event-for-each-li-not-all/12316753#12316753), it's very similar.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can avoid closure and use `event.data` instead.
This looks cleaner to me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        $(document).on('click','#del_od' + i,{'index': i},function(e) {
            var index = e.data.index;
            $('#change_od' + index).val('YES');
            $('#span_od' + index).html('(Deleted)');
            $('#status_od' + index).val('DELETED'); 
        })
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/42Hz4/)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can serve them all with one event handler by parsing the id suffix out of the id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','[id^="del_"]', function() {
        var suffix = this.id.replace(/^.*?_/, "");
        $('#change_' + suffix).val('YES');
        $('#span_' + suffix).html('(Deleted)');
        $('#status_' + suffix).val('DELETED');
    });
});
```

This can also be solved by using the HTML relationship of the delete button to the affected items.

If you could modify the HTML to use classes for the various targets, then it could be done like this without any ids, by just using the relationship of the pressed button to the desired target:

```
    <tr>
        <td>'.$aDoc_parts[0].'</td>
        <td>
            <span id="span_od'  . $ocnt . '" class="spanTarget">
                <a href="'.$aDoc_parts[1].'" target="blank">
                '. $aDoc_parts[1] .'
                </a>
            </span>
            <input type="hidden" id="status_od' . $ocnt . '" class="statusTarget" name="status_od' . $ocnt . '">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="change_od' . $ocnt . '" class="changeTarget normal" href="#">change</a>
            <input type="file" id="if_od' . $ocnt . '" name="if_od' . $ocnt . '" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" style="display:none">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="del_od' class="deleteButton" . $ocnt . '">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>';
```

And, this would be the script based only on position and classes (no ids):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
        parent.find('.changeTarget').val('YES');
        parent.find('.spanTarget').html('(Deleted)');
        parent.find('.statusTarget').val('DELETED');
    });
});
```

This gets the row that the delete button that was clicked was in and then finds the change, span and status objects that are in the same row and operates on them.  No ids are used at all.  This uses the position of the clicked on button to find the objects that it operates on.

Comment: Please explain your regex: this.id.replace(/^.*?_/, ""); ?

Comment: @gibberish - It takes the id value of the delete button that was pressed like `del_od1` and gets rid of the first part (replaces it with nothing) so we just have the suffix `od1` which can be attached to the various prefixes.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse, but please elaborate: "by using the HTML relationship of the delete button to the affected items"

Comment: @gibberish - it took me a few moments to write the second version.  I've added it to my answer.  You add a unique class to each change, span and status item in the row.  When the delete button is pressed, you find the row you're in and the find the change, span and status objects that are also in that row and operate on them.

Comment: The Javascript part of your second solution is good (it's essentially how I would do it), but the PHP/HTML isn't, since you're creating duplicate IDs.

Comment: @Barmar - The ids are unchanged from the OP's code and are not used by my second version of javascript so I just left them in place with what the OP had.  I don't think it makes duplicate ids, as I think the ids are incremented with a counter.

Comment: The OP's code had `. $ocnt` after each of the IDs. You're missing it after `id="span_od`.

Comment: @Barmar - OK, I fixed that.  The PHP template stuff is greek to me.  I  was just trying to insert a `class="spanTarget"` somewhere safe.  Feel free to propose an actual edit of my answer to fix things like that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, that may have been why your code didn't work for me. I've awarded the points to roXon (as his code is what worked and is now in my project) but I'll revisit yours and upvote if it works with your revs. Thanks for the help.